# Why does HDD make noise even when I don't use it?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, noise

I have an SSD for boot drive and an HDD for data storage in my Windows 10 PC.
Loading a new webpage at the Chrome browser makes a noise from the HDD which is very weird.

Comment: Is your Windows swapfile on that HDD?

Comment: ...or browser cache?

Comment: What kind of noise? Have you checked the disk for SMART errors?

Comment: You can use Sysinternals Process Monitor for tracking all disk operations to the HDD drive.